# Fragment is not starting from menu item when pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragment-manager

I'm trying to start a fragment from the toolbar (the toolbar is in a fragment too) but it's not starting, that was not the case when it was in the main activity it was working fine.

> If You Want More Reference of any file or want to see other files
> please tell me I will upload it

**Java Files**

**Home_Fragment.java**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    MaterialToolbar materialToolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
            materialToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(toolbarItemClickListener);
return view;
    }
    
    private final MaterialToolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener toolbarItemClickListener =
            (MenuItem item) -> {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search_button) {
                    selectedFragment = new Search_Fragment();
                }
               
                return true;
            };
```

**XML Files**

**tool_bar.xml(menu XML)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"/>

</menu>
```

**tool_bar.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:itemIconSize="29dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:menu="@menu/tool_bar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just created a new instance of your Fragment, but didn't add it to the FragmentManager, so it didn't start. You have to make a FragmentTransaction to start the fragment.

Fragment selectedFragment = null;

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search_button) {
    selectedFragment = new Search_Fragment();
    getParentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, Search_Fragment.class, null) // fragment_container is the ID of the fragment holder
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: getParentFragmentManager is giving me error

Comment: can you tell me a simple way to do it like creating a new intent or something like this and also I want to add a backstack

Comment: If your want to place Search_Fragment inside HomeFragment, then use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getParentFragmentManager(). For adding into backstack, use .addToBackStack(null) before .commit()